# Nexmo text-to-speech break right a way when answers

Tags: laravel, text-to-speech, lumen, vonage

I tray to make text to speech in my app using Nexmo composer package. SMS works well but have problem with T2S service. When I send request it calls me but when I click answer it end a call.
Here is example of json what is added into T2S call:

```
[ "{ "action": "talk", 
"text": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam ut ligula nec quam pulvinar rn bibendum. Sed nisi ipsum, pretium tempor bibendum vel, condimentum ut erat. Vivamus sagittis, rn mi eget tincidunt laoreet, diam ligula euismod nisi, sit amet maximus ipsum arcu facilisis erat. rn Donec sed efficitur enim. Phasellus sagittis pulvinar semper. Pellentesque quis nibh sed neque rn maximus sodales. Morbi vel ornare elit. ", 
"voiceName": "Salli" }" ]
```

I also try with this one:

```
{ "action": "talk", 
"text": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam ut ligula nec quam pulvinar rn bibendum. Sed nisi ipsum, pretium tempor bibendum vel, condimentum ut erat. Vivamus sagittis, rn mi eget tincidunt laoreet, diam ligula euismod nisi, sit amet maximus ipsum arcu facilisis erat. rn Donec sed efficitur enim. Phasellus sagittis pulvinar semper. Pellentesque quis nibh sed neque rn maximus sodales. Morbi vel ornare elit. ", 
"voiceName": "Salli" }
```

but none works.

Here is example of send call to me and make file into S3 which Nexmo will read:

```
$json_file = str_random(16).'.json';

        $data = [
            'action' => 'talk',
            'text' => $event->notification->content.' '.$event->arrived_in,
            'voiceName' => 'Salli'
        ];

        $newJsonString = json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);

        $this->flysystem->connection('awss3');
        $this->flysystem->write('call_cleanup_notifications/'.$json_file, stripslashes($newJsonString));

        $basic  = new Basic(getenv('NEXMO_KEY'), getenv('NEXMO_SECRET'));

        $this->flysystem->connection('awss3');
        $key = $this->flysystem->read('application.key');

        $keypair = new Keypair($key, getenv('NEXMO_APPLICATION_ID'));

        $client = new Client(new Container($basic, $keypair));
$client->calls()->create([
            'to' => [[
                'type' => 'phone',
                'number' => $event->cleanupUserChanel->home_phone_number
            ]],
            'from' => [
                'type' => 'phone',
                'number' => getenv('NEXMO_SMS_FROM')
            ],
            'answer_url' => [getenv('GATEWAY_API_URL').'/notification_call/'.$json_file],
        ]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is solution for make this json T2S file in valid format:

```
            $json_file = str_random(16) . '.json';
            $data[] = (object) [
                'action' => 'talk',
                'text' => "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit",
                'voiceName' => 'Salli'
            ];
//save file in file system using flysystem composer package
            $this->flysystem->write($json_file, json_encode($data,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are pretty close with that first example, but the NCCO isn't quite valid JSON. At the start, after the `[`, remove the quote `"` before the object starts at the `{`.  (then do the same at the end, remove the last quote before the `]`.  Hope that helps!

Comment: I think I am fix it but it still not works. Now it's back to me this:
`{
  "action": "talk",
  "text": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam ut ligula nec quam pulvinar...",
  "voiceName": "Salli"
}`

Comment: It is an array of objects so you need the square brackets `[` `] `outside the curly ones